# How can I make multidimensional associative array in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, multidimensional-array

I want to make a data structure like multidimensional associative array in Delphi.

I know that there is `TObjectDictionary`. But making multidimensional array with TObjectDictionary is so hard and not efficient I think.

Is there any other good approach to make multidimensional associative array in Delphi?

Comment: Why is using `TDictionary` inefficient for your needs? Why is it hard? Also, it's hard to recommend a class design without any requirements. Do you know what the requirements are?

Comment: Maybe you could explain the behavior of what you call "Multidimension associative array" and in which way it is different than `TDictionary`.

Comment: @AlexSC Presumably asker wants to write `dict[foo][bar]` where `foo` and `bar` have arbitrary types

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, you are right. I want to write dict[foo][bar][a][b] with arbitrary types.

Comment: We still don't know any detailed requirements, and why you can't build it out of `TDictionary`. If we start writing code samples for you, or suggesting solutions, you'll say, "Ah, but I need this functionality, and that capability, and so on." Please be clear on your requirements.

Comment: If you would like to use PHP arrays you may need to use PHP. However in Delphi TDictionary is as close as it gets.

Answer (score 5):

TDictionary is hash-based, so performance will not seriously degrade for any number of dimensions. Two-dimensional version of dictionary can be implementation like this:

```
  T2DimDictionary<TDim1,TDim2,TValue> = class
  private
    function GetValue(x: TDim1; y: TDim2): TValue;
    procedure SetValue(x: TDim1; y: TDim2; const Value: TValue);
  protected
    FDictionary: TObjectDictionary<TDim1, TDictionary<TDim2, TValue>>;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property Values[x: TDim1; y: TDim2]: TValue read GetValue write SetValue; default;
  end;

{ T2DimDictionary }

constructor T2DimDictionary<TDim1,TDim2,TValue>.Create;
begin
  FDictionary := TObjectDictionary<TDim1, TDictionary<TDim2, TValue>>.Create;
end;

destructor T2DimDictionary<TDim1,TDim2,TValue>.Destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil(FDictionary);
  inherited;
end;

function T2DimDictionary<TDim1,TDim2,TValue>.GetValue(x: TDim1; y: TDim2): TValue;
var
  SubArray: TDictionary<TDim2, TValue>;
begin
  if not FDictionary.TryGetValue(x, SubArray) or
    not SubArray.TryGetValue(y, result)
  then
    raise exception.Create('Error');
end;

procedure T2DimDictionary<TDim1,TDim2,TValue>.SetValue(x: TDim1; y: TDim2;
  const Value: TValue);
var
  SubArray: TDictionary<TDim2, TValue>;
begin
  if not FDictionary.TryGetValue(x, SubArray) then
  begin
    SubArray := TDictionary<TDim2, TValue>.Create;
    FDictionary.Add(x, SubArray);
  end;
  SubArray.AddOrSetValue(y, Value);
end;

var
  d: T2DimDictionary<integer, string, string>;
begin
  d := T2DimDictionary<integer, string, string>.Create;
  d[1,'january'] := 'test1';
  d[1,'march'] := 'test2';
  assert(d[1,'january']='test1');
  FreeAndNil(d);
end;
```

Alternatively you can use single TDictionary with complex key based on all "dimensions".